# set iTerm tab title to current folder + last command

Tags: iterm

I followed these directions to set my tab titles to the operating folder:
https://gist.github.com/phette23/5270658?permalink_comment_id=3020766#gistcomment-3020766

This is pretty cool… now my tab is titled **someFolder (node)** when I'm running `yarn develop` in a web app. But I run different processes out of the same folder, also `yarn test` and `yarn storybook`

Is there a way to instead display the last command entered (or the command that initiated the currently-running process)? What I'd really like is a tab titled **someFolder (yarn develop)**.

Comment: Link-only answer (not checked in iTerm): http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070628002730528